# Relacionamento de tabelas

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, inner

Boa Noite,
tenho um banco de dados  com varias tabelas e preciso fazer uma consulta relacionamento 4 tabelas

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cad_cliente` (
      `id_cliente` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `nome_cliente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `nome_dr` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `email_cliente` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `data_nascimento_cliente` date NOT NULL,
      `endereco_cliente` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
      `bairro_cliente` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `cep_cliente` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
      `cidade_cliente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
      `estado_cliente` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
      `observacao` varchar(45) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cad_paciente` (
     `id_paciente` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `nome_paciente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_cliente` varchar(45) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cad_trabalho` (
     `id_trabalho` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
     `id_cliente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_paciente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_dente` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_servico` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `id_cor` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `observacao_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `data_entrada_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `data_saida_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `pronto_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `valor_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `pagamento_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `foto1_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `foto2_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
     `foto3_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL
   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cad_estagio` (
  `id_estagio` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `id_trabalho` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `data_estagio` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `id_funcionario` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_estagio` varchar(45) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

agora quero relacionar estas tabelas em uma unica consulta para exibir os dados delas da seguinte maneira

> id_trabalho, nome_cliente, nome_paciente, data_saida_trabalho, id_funcionario

sendo que na tabela `cad_estagio` podera ter varios estagios cadastrados para o mesmo `id_trabalho` como faço para exibir essas informações no phpmyadmin eu consigo com o seguinte SELECT

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(data_saida_trabalho, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_saida FROM cad_trabalho
JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente = cad_paciente.id_paciente
JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN cad_estagio ON cad_trabalho.id_trabalho = cad_estagio.id_trabalho
WHERE cad_trabalho.pronto_trabalho = '0000-00-00' ORDER BY data_saida_trabalho ASC
```

SO que quando exibo eles na pagina eles vem duplicado os mesmos `id_trabalho` com todos os estagios cadastrados para aquele `id_trabalho` e nao exibe o `id_trabalho` para os outros resultados que nao tenha estagio cadastrados, meu php esta da seguinte forma

```
 /* resultado da consulta */
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(data_saida_trabalho, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_saida FROM cad_trabalho
JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente = cad_paciente.id_paciente
JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN cad_estagio ON cad_trabalho.id_trabalho = cad_estagio.id_trabalho
WHERE cad_trabalho.pronto_trabalho = '0000-00-00' ORDER BY data_saida_trabalho ASC");


        /* começa a construir a tabela no HTML */
        echo "<table><tr><th width='50'>COD</th><th width='250'>Cliente</th><th width='250'>Paciente</th><th width='100'>Data Entrega</th><th width='50'>Editar</th><th width='50'>Estagio</th></tr>";

        /* percorre o retorno da consulta */
        while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
            /* dentro do $row[] vai o nome da coluna da sua consulta */
            echo "<tr><td>$row->id_trabalho</td><td>$row->nome_cliente</td><td>$row->nome_paciente</td><td>$row->data_saida</td><td><a href=editar_trabalho.php?id=$row->id_trabalho>Editar</a></td><td><a href=editar_estagio.php?id=$row->id_trabalho>Estagio - $row->id_funcionario</a></td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Tentou usar o GROUP BY cad_trabalho.id_paciente? Sem agrupar vem duplicado os registros... Ao menos nos meus Sql eu agrupo tudo.

Comment: Não faço a minima ideia de como se usa. rsrsrs so sei o basico estou me aperfeiçoando ainda

Comment: Me chame no Skype, que eu te ajudo: srandrebaill

Comment: @AndréBaill Por que não conversam aqui no [chat] mesmo? Assim pelo menos a ajuda fica disponível para outras pessoas.

Comment: Sou novo aqui bfavaretto... não entendo muito bem como funciona, pra chamar no chat e tals... por isso pedi pra ele add no skype :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue o SQL testado pelo banco de dados que me passou... Pelo o que entendi, seria isso.

```
SELECT * FROM cad_estagio AS cde 
LEFT JOIN cad_trabalho ON cad_trabalho.id_trabalho = cde.id_trabalho 
LEFT JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente = cad_paciente.id_paciente
LEFT JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
WHERE cad_trabalho.pronto_trabalho = '0000-00-00'
ORDER BY cde.id_estagio DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Opa consegui solucionar com o seguinte SELECT

```
SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(data_saida_trabalho, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_saida FROM cad_trabalho
JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente = cad_paciente.id_paciente
JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN cad_estagio ON cad_trabalho.id_trabalho = cad_estagio.id_trabalho ORDER BY cad_estagio.id_estagio DESC
WHERE cad_trabalho.pronto_trabalho = '0000-00-00'
GROUP BY cad_trabalho.id_paciente
ORDER BY data_saida_trabalho ASC
```

Mas agora como faço para quando for mostrar o `cad_estagio.id_estagio` ele me mostre o ultimo para `cad_trabalho.id_trabalho`??

Answer (score 1):

Com a ajuda do @AndreBaill chegamos ao seguinte SELECT

```
SELECT *,cad_trabalho.id_trabalho as trabalho, DATE_FORMAT(data_saida_trabalho, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_saida, DATE_FORMAT(cad_estagio.data_estagio, '%d/%m/%Y') AS data_estagio FROM cad_trabalho
JOIN cad_paciente ON cad_trabalho.id_paciente = cad_paciente.id_paciente
JOIN cad_cliente ON cad_paciente.id_cliente = cad_cliente.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN cad_estagio ON cad_trabalho.id_trabalho = cad_estagio.id_trabalho and cad_estagio.id_estagio = (select max(id_estagio) from cad_estagio where id_trabalho = cad_trabalho.id_trabalho)
WHERE cad_trabalho.pronto_trabalho = '0000-00-00'
GROUP BY cad_trabalho.id_paciente
ORDER BY cad_trabalho.data_saida_trabalho ASC
```

Que resolveu o meu problema, Obrigado mano